# Setting the Comparison Value For All __lt__, __gt__, __eq__, etc?

Tags: python

Is it possible to set the comparison value for all comparison operations?

I've done something like this:

```
@dataclass
class _Leaf(Generic[T]):
    parent: _Leaf
    value: T

    def __init__(self, value: Optional[T] = None):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = self

    def update(self, value: T):
        self.value = value
        return self

    def __lt__(self, other: _Leaf):
        return repr(self) < repr(other)

    def __gt__(self, other: _Leaf):
        return repr(self) > repr(other)

    def __eq__(self, other: _Leaf):
        return repr(self) == repr(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
```

But this is more of a convention rather than something built into python and I later found that this does not work when I want to compare tuples. I could come up with a `__val__` of my own and use that but I don't want to add functionality if it already exists. Is there something like my proposed `__val__` that I can use?

```
@dataclass
class _Leaf(Generic[T]):
    parent: _Leaf
    value: T

    def __init__(self, value: Optional[T] = None):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = self

    def update(self, value: T):
        self.value = value
        return self

    def __val__(self):
        return self.value
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `@dataclass(order=True)` (generate all the comparison methods) then `parent: _Leaf = field(compare=False)` (exclude the `parent` attribute from the tuple for comparison)?

Comment: The point of ``repr`` is to create a *string* representation, not some arbitrary alternate one. ``__repr__`` must return a ``str`` or various functions will just break.

Comment: The code shows a ``dataclass`` but doesn't really use it and neither title nor body make mention of it. Since ``dataclass`` has builtin support for comparisons, are you actually asking about the ``dataclass`` case or a general one?

Answer (score 1):

The functools module has a decorator called [total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) that almost exactly does that for you. You just have to define one of the comparison operators and ideally the `__eq__` operator and the rest will be derived from those.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a protocol, supporing a generic `__val__` method.
You can either cast your class to a comparable type by implementing the respective protocol function, iff applicable, such as `__float__`, `__int__` and compare the casted values via `int(obj) <= int(other)` instead.

If you need custom functions to compare your objects in other manners, have a look at [`functools.total_ordering()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).